# How find this $f(\overline{E})=\overline{f(E)} \Longleftrightarrow ?$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f : R^n\to R^m$ be a continuous map. What is a necessary and sufficient condition for
$$f(\overline{E})=\overline{f(E)}  \Longleftrightarrow ?$$
to hold for every $E \subseteq R^n$?

I guess this maybe  necessary and sufficient conditions $f$ is constant?

But I can't true this is right?

so someone   can  help me?Thank you very much

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean here; is the $f(\overline E) = \overline{f(E)}$ condition supposed to hold for all $E \subset \mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Yes,@DustanLevenstein,Thank you

Comment: It's certainly not necessary that $f$ be constant; consider the identity function with $n=m$, or, for that matter, any homeomorphism with $n=m$.

Comment: so this problem  answer is? Thank you

Comment: I don't know the answer (although I have a guess). That's the beauty of mathematics; you need to figure these things out. :)

Comment: It's certainly always true if $E$ is bounded. Basically, for it not to be true, you'd need an unbounded sequence of $x_1,x_2,\dots$ with no convergent subsequence and $f(x_i)$ convergent to some point outside $f(E)$.

Answer (score 2):

A function $f : X \to Y$ between topological spaces satisfies $f(\overline{E}) = \overline{f(E)}$ for all $E \subseteq X$ (i.e., commutes with closures) iff it is continuous and closed: continuity is equivalent to $f(\overline{E}) \subseteq \overline{f(E)}$ for all $E$, and given this, equality holds iff $f$ is closed.